# MySQL sporadic refused connections

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to identify an issue for a couple weeks now where one of my database servers running MySQL 8 is sporadically returning Connection Refused but then on subsequent attempts the connection works.  I've checked all the logs I can think of and am coming up empty handed.  To me, it seems there's some kind of sleep timeout or something where it wakes back up after a connection is attempted over port 3306.

Just this morning I attempted a connection using telnet.  It immediately failed and then the subsequent attempt a few seconds later worked.  I'm at a loss.

Has anyone ran into this and knows what's going on or has some tips for things to check?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to this (it may have been the same issue), and I solved it by increasing the connect timeout with `connectiontimeout=300` in the connection string. You may not need to use a value as large as `300` but it works fine for me:

```
server=.;protocol=pipe;pipename=MySQL;connectiontimeout=300;database=mydb;uid=root;pwd=blah
```

I also felt that there was some kind of "sleeping" going on after some time had passed, and the first connection to "wake" the database would always fail. However, after using `connectiontimeout=300`, instead of the first connection failing, it just took a few extra seconds to connect and worked fine.